# row container start from center

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row

```
<div class="row">

</div>
```

I'm inserting some dynamic content inside this container

with the following snippet

```
<div class="col-md-2 " style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
    <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
</div>
```

Ex code looks like:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2 " style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
            <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 " style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
            <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 " style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
            <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 " style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
            <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
        </div>
    .......
</div>
```

here I want the content to display from center,
means

if it has only one image show it in center, 
if it has 2 images show those 2 images in center
like wise if I have 6 images it should display in a complete row,
If it has more show them in next row **middle**

How to do this?

**EDIT**
My question is if there is only one .col-md-2 show that in center of the page,if there are multiple .col-md-2 then show both at the middle,if there are six then it covers all the page

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this.. You can center any element within its parent.

```
.center-block() {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container {
  width: 940px;  
}
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

Use css for center align

```
text-align:center;
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.text-center
```

its a bootstrap class. have a look at the [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ku935tLa0B)

**Updated**

Comment: have a look at it now. but, get rid of the margin between the col-md-2's because it will make the 6th coloumn go down to the next row

Answer (score 0):

G.L.P Solution Worked for me

```
.center-block{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

and call this class in col-md-3 div each div u call it like that

so final code is

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-2 center-block" style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
        <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-2 center-block" style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
        <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-2 center-block" style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
        <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-2 center-block" style="padding-bottom:2px;margin-left: 1px;" >
        <a href="/profile"><img src="{{imgurl}}" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
    </div>
```

i'm sorry man my reputation is low so i cant rate or comment on ur comment.